# Resolving MultivarLimit $3x^2y/(x^2+y^2)$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ by approach

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm resolving the limit of $\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$  when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

We didn't study any specal theorem, we did only approach.

I tried first the suggested changes $y=mx$ and $y=x^2-x^3$.

In $f(x,mx)$ I get that the $lim =0$,operating I get $\frac{3xm}{1+m^2}$ that is lim $0/1=0$
and then makes a change $f(x,x^2-x^3)$ and then factorizing $x^2$ the denominator and then simplifing I get 
$\frac{3x^2-3x^3}{1+x^2-2x^3+x^4}$ then appling L'Hopital $\frac{6x-9x^2}{2x-6x^2+4x^3}$
factorizing x on the numerator and denominator I get $\frac{6-9x}{2-6x+4x^2}$ so the limit =$6/2$ and then not exist becouse one gives me $0$,and the other $6/2$
Is right the procedure? Any way to do it easy?
Thanks.

Comment: the formula in your question and in title are not the same maybe a typo ?

Comment: Thanks,really centrated in that gets well with frac, and nevermind that edited incorrectly, the correct is $3x^2*y/(x^2+y^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{3x^2 y}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\underbrace{\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|}_{\leq 1}|3y|\leq 3|y|\underset{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\longrightarrow }0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{3y}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2}\leq 3y$$
thus the limit is zero.